# $g(x,y)=f(\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$ for (x,y) is not zero vector. Show that $y\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=x\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$.

Tags: partial-derivative

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.
I think it need Euler's theorem to solve it. But I do not know the homogeneous degree of g. My attempt is $$g(tx,ty)=f(\sqrt {(tx)^2+(ty)^2})=f(|x|\sqrt {x^2+y^2})$$
Another question is can I say g (two variable function) is differentiable since f (one variable function) is differentiable?

Comment: All  you have to do is calculate the partial derivatives. No theorem on homogeneous functions is needed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks!

Comment: Concerning your other question, recall that a partial derivative is just an ordinary derivative by one variable while all the other independent variables are held constant. And by the ordinary chain rule, the composition of two differentiable functions is differentiable.